# Attach policy to a IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

Following cloudformation template gives error on line 9 :

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
"Description" : "Policy to allow send receive message from SQS Queue",
"Resources" : {
"MyPolicy" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::IAM::Policy",
    "Properties" : {
        "PolicyName" : "CFUsers",
        "Roles": [ { "arn:aws:iam::710161973367:role/Cognito_CFIAuth_Role" } ],
        "PolicyDocument" : {
            "Version" : "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "Sid1482400105445",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                    "AWS":         "arn:aws:iam::710161973367:role/Cognito_CFIAuth_Role"
                },
                "Action": [
                    "SQS:SendMessage",
                    "SQS:ReceiveMessage",
                    "SQS:DeleteMessage",
                    "SQS:GetQueueUrl"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:710161973367:CFI-Trace"
            }
            ]
        }
    }
 }
 }
```

I want role Cognito_CFIAuth_Role to have message send/read/delete previleges on SQS queue CFI-Trace. How do I attach SQS operation privileges to IAM Role ?

Comment: Strictly from a syntax perspective, `[ { "arn:aws:iam::710161973367:role/Cognito_CFIAuth_Role" } ],` is indeed wrong, as it's an array containing an object with a key but no value. The `{` and `}` are incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

First, Line 9 contains a JSON syntax error, the brackets `{}` around your Role string should be removed:

```
        "Roles": [ "arn:aws:iam::710161973367:role/Cognito_CFIAuth_Role" ],
```

Second, [`AWS::IAM::Policy`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html)'s [`Roles`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html#cfn-iam-policy-roles) property accepts "The **names** of `AWS::IAM::Role`s to attach to this policy", not full ARNs, so your line should be:

```
        "Roles": [ "Cognito_CFIAuth_Role" ],
```

You also need a missing closing bracket `}` at the end of your example.

Answer (score 1):

With the `AWS::IAM::Policy` resource, you're creating an *inline* policy.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html explains that this takes a list of "The names of `AWS::IAM::Roles`, which I take to be the logical name of role resources defined within the same stack.

If you want to attach the policy to a preexisting role, you should use the **ManagedPolicy** type instead.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-managedpolicy.html#cfn-iam-managedpolicy-roles takes the name of the preexisting role(s).

Comment: Additionally, it has to be valid JSON.  See @michael's comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudformation type IAM::Policy is for Users and Groups. Roles and instance profiles are for ec2. You have conflated both ideas. If you have the role predefined in a different CFN then you use just an Instance Profile for your EC2 instance, if not you can create it too and then ref it

```
"RootInstanceProfile": {
     "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
     "Properties": {
        "Path": "/",
        "Roles": [ {
           "arn:aws:iam::710161973367:role/Cognito_CFIAuth_Role"
        } ]
     }
  }
```

or

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
  "SQSRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": [
                "ec2.amazonaws.com"
              ]
            },
            "Action": [
              "sts:AssumeRole"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Path": "/",
    "Policies": [
      {
        "PolicyName": "root",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "SQS:SendMessage",
                "SQS:ReceiveMessage",
                "SQS:DeleteMessage",
                "SQS:GetQueueUrl"
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-south-1:710161973367:CFI-Trace"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
    "RootInstanceProfile": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile",
      "Properties": {
        "Path": "/",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "SQSRole"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

IAM Policy

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-policy.html

IAM role
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html

Now there is also SQS Policy
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-policy.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also attach `ManagedPolicyArns` to CloudFormation resource type `AWS::IAM::Role` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-managepolicyarns